# Python Seaborn Pandas bar chart problem - same years for different states

Tags: bar-chart, seaborn

So I have this dataFrame I'm using -

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEMql.png)

and I am trying to show a bar chart of the data, such that for each state I could see the number of incidents per year, for each of the years in the df.

I've got so far with this-

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpNgg.png)

but the thing is that every state has different time frames - meaning the graph supposed to be showing different years. (i.e Arizona for 89-95 and Maryland for 87-93), but I get the same years for all states.

What should I do?

my code is -

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(dfagg, col="State")
g.map(sns.barplot, "Year", "Incident")
```

where dfagg is the df mentioned earlier.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `sharex=False` to the FacetGrid function:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(dfagg, col="State", sharex=False)
g.map(sns.barplot, "Year", "Incident")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the axis by:

```
ax.set(ylim=(<min year>, <max year>))
```